# Create a two items per row list from array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array that I am iterating over to display some data as a list. My code below displays the data in one column:

```
                    return (
                      <li style={litags}>
                        <span style={tags} key={index1}>
                          {name1}
                        </span>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
```

However, I want it to show the data in the following format instead, with a number at the beginning of each row and two elements per row:

> 1. element1 element2
> 2. element3 element4
> 3. element5 element6
> 4. element7 element8
> 5. element9 element10

I'm thinking maybe I need some type of `i % 2 === 0` in there, or a way display `i + 1` to get the element on the right, but I just can't figure it out!

Any ideas on how to do this?

Edit: Answered but additional info below regarding comments Q&A:

````
 {data.history().map((each, index) => {
                    if (index % 2 === 0) {
                      return (
                        <ul>
                          <li style={{ liststyletype: 'none' }}>
                            <span>
                              {index / 2 + 1}.{each}
                              &nbsp;
                              {data.history()[index + 1]}
                            </span>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
    ```
````

Comment: Could be, but the first thing came to my mind is just do it with CSS grid. It's way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
{data.map((each, index) => {
                if (index % 2 === 0) {
                    return (
                        <li>
                            <span>
                                {index / 2 + 1}.{each}
                                {data[index + 1]}
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    );
                }
            })}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is amazing! It worked nicely. :) What would you do to put a space between each bit of data on the same row? Do I add a " " or something? I need to hide the bullet too, although I think that is a css job using `list-style-type: none;` or something.

Comment: You can put each data inside a span and style it. Yes, to hide the bullet just use list-style-type: none in li tag.

Comment: I have slightly modified code which I put into the last part of my original post. I tried the `liststyletype:'none'` but it didn't remove the bullet. Any ideas why?

Comment: The right syntax is: listStyleType. React using camel case, when you convert css to react inline style you upper the letter behind the "-" in css.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew that! Thanks, it is working now. I tried the liststyletype before and never got it to work. It was the camelcase thing. Making progress!

Comment: I've just hit another snag I did not anticipate. Not sure if I should open a new stackoverflow question for this. I now have my numbered list which looks great. However, the second item on the row is not left aligned with all the items below it. It is jagged. So, I figure I need a two column layout for this. I tried adding `columnCount: '2'` to the ul style, but it is still jagged. Any recommendations on where to look?

Comment: How did you style it? You should post another question with the style and maybe some picture.  I cant imagine how it look now.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thanks for the advice. You were great.

Comment: I explained how I styled it etc here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625916/styling-a-list-with-2-columns But no replies so perhaps its a bit tricky to do.